# How to short URL for run-time changing variable in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried to short the URL. In the URL, i removed index.php and controller name. After that when i select a row that index value is passed to the URL. So every time when i click on different pages or different rows , the value changed in URL. So i don't know how to change the URL. Anybody guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: Show the code first please ...!

Comment: Just a note if your using codeigniter 3 and testing in a localhost and have left your base url blank then some links will not work correct. In ci3 versions it's now best to set your base url in config.php

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter have typical mvc construct. So it have short url to seperately.
You will know that opened routes.php in directory of application/configs.
There, codeigniter have shorturl.

Comment: My URL is 'http://127.0.0.1/codesearch/pagination/index/12' and i want to short the 'pagination/index/12' it into single name. And in my hands i have a code '$route['short/(:num)']='pagination/index/$1'; '... This is for single value , not for run time changing value and also i don't know how to use it .

Comment: you will define short url in routes.php.

Comment: Don't you know mean '$route['short/(:num)']='pagination/index/$1'?

Comment: Ya i don't know the mean of  '$route['short/(:num)']='pagination/index/$1'. And how to use it in automatic redirecting when the value is very for each click.

Comment: OK, codeigniter is do filter your url. So, you will define your all url in routes.php. Example, if you are making short url('127.0.0.1/codesearch/examplepage/), you will define route['examplepage']='*********'.

Comment: Here, ********* is controller file, if it is 'pagination/index/$1', this will do mean  index function in pagination.php of controllers directory.

Comment: your code (:num) in $route['short/(:num)'] is mean parameter value

Comment: in word, index function in pagination.php have one's parameter, It is number format.